# Duda pasar instancia de webdriver como parametro en funcion python

Tags: java, python

Holas

Estoy empezando con python y tengo la duda como puedo pasar una instancia de un webdriver de selenium por parametro a una funcion en python, con el fin de que este lenguaje me reconozca el tipo de objeto y asi me sugiera cierta funciones con el autocompletado.

En java se me hacia mas facil, ya que en los argumentos de las funciones definia el tipo de variable.

//En java

```
public boolean login(Webdriver driver, String username, String password) {

    driver.click();
}
```

//En python no se como forzar o pedir un elemento tipo webdriver, para que me vayaa sugiriendo funciones.

```
def login(driver):

    driver
```

Comment: El _autocompletado_ no es algo propio del lenguaje, sino del entorno de desarrollo que estés usando. En general, hay que tener en cuenta que python usa _tipos dinámicos_, por lo que el argumento que pasas a una función no se sabe con seguridad de qué tipo es hasta el momento de su ejecución. No obstante, hay IDEs y librerías que son capaces de inferir el tipo de dato analizando el código de un proyecto y la instalación python que estés usando. Prueba, por ejemplo, la [extensión python para vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_autocomplete-and-intellisense).

Comment: Al margen de lo que @ChemaCortes te indica en su comentario. Python3 admite los llamados [_type hints_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) que son unas declaraciones del tipo de las variables (parámetros, datos retornados por una función) con una sintaxis especial. El intérprete ignora los tipos (es decir, no te va a dar un error si usas el tipo incorrecto), pero los IDEs pueden usarlos para autocompletado, sugerencias, o warnings. Si tienes más interés sobre este tema indícalo en un comentario.

Comment: A tu pregunta _¿como puedo pasar una instancia de un webdriver de selenium por parametro?_ la respuesta sería: así como lo estás haciendo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En *Python*, al ser un lenguaje de tipado dinámico, no se especifica el tipo de las variables. Se pueden hacer anotaciones de tipos, pero estas anotaciones son ignoradas por el intérprete (no suponen un mejor rendimiento del programa).

Si lo que quieres es asegurarte de que el parámetro pasado es de tipo *Webdriver* podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
def login(driver):
    if isinstance(driver, webdriver):
        # Trabajar con normalidad.
    else:
        # Mostrar error.
```

Es decir, puedes comprobar si el parámetro pasado es una instancia de la clase *Webdriver* mediante la función predefinida **isinstance**.

En cuanto al **autocompletado**, por el mismo motivo (es un lenguaje tipado dinámico) los *IDEs* no ofrecen un buen autocompletado, sin embargo para este propósito te interesará echar un vistazo a [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Por otra parte, para ver los métodos de una clase, puedes abrir una consola interactiva de *Python*:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> webdriver.__dir__()
['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__path__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__', 'firefox', 'common', 'remote', 'Firefox', 'FirefoxProfile', 'FirefoxOptions', 'chrome', 'Chrome', 'ChromeOptions', 'ie', 'Ie', 'IeOptions', 'edge', 'Edge', 'opera', 'Opera', 'safari', 'Safari', 'blackberry', 'support', 'BlackBerry', 'phantomjs', 'PhantomJS', 'android', 'Android', 'webkitgtk', 'WebKitGTK', 'WebKitGTKOptions', 'Remote', 'DesiredCapabilities', 'ActionChains', 'TouchActions', 'Proxy', '__version__']
```

O sea, que la forma de explorar los atributos y métodos de una clase sería utilizar el método **__dir__** de la clase (que devuelve una lista) en una consola interactiva de *Python*.